# Display 2 different size ads from the same campaign ( same ad creative but different size)

Tags: android, ads, google-dfp, double-click-advertising

The question is referring to the Android SDK.

I want to display an Interstitial ad and when that ad is closed and the user returns to the activity, I want to display a banner ad but with from the same advertiser and the same campaign. Basically the same ad but displayed in a different view size and different type ad format.

Can you get something like an ad id or campaign id from the Interstitial ad and set the banner ad to serve 
with the same ids ?

Can this be done, or I haven't yet understand how the whole delivery system works?